# ifstream sets failbit when trying to read a textfile

Tags: c++

My problem is that the "failbit" is set directly when trying to read a textfile. The strange thing, for me at least, is that if I build my program and run it, it works. But when I try to debug it the failbit sets.

The actual error message I get is this:

> "Unhandled exception at 0x7740c41f in Steg1_1A.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::ios_base::failure at memory location 0x003bf8e4.."

And the text to the console program is this: "ios_base::failbit set".

The question is, how do I fix so failbit doesn't "crash the program" when debugging?

Here is my function:

```
void selectedMenuChoice(int choice)
{
int index = 0, initValue = 0;
const int fileNumberCount = 24;
double numFromFile = 0.0, sum = 0.0, average = 0.0, max = 0.0, min = 0.0;

switch (choice)
{
    // "Display temperature values"
    case 1:
        cout << "\nDisplaying the latest 24 temperature values:\n\n";
        break;

    // "View maximum and minimum temperatures"
    case 2:
        cout << "\nCalculating the maximum and minimum temperature...\n";
        break;

    // "View average temperature"
    case 3:
        cout << "\nCalculating average temperature...\n";
        break;
}

ifstream file;

file.exceptions(ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit);
try 
{
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Here is the problem. It throws an exception directly when debugging
    file.open("templog.txt"); // filnamnet 
    //file.fail();

    // "View maximum and minimum temperatures"
    if (choice == 2)
    {
        initValue = 1;
        file >> numFromFile;
        max = min = numFromFile;
    }

    // Loopar igenom filen dock baserat på ett konstantvärde.
    for (index = initValue; index < fileNumberCount; index++)
    {
        file >> numFromFile;

        switch (choice)
        {
            // "Display temperature values"
            case 1:
                if (index % 6 == 0)
                {
                    cout << endl;
                }
                cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(8) << numFromFile;
                break;

            // "View maximum and minimum temperatures"
            case 2:
                if (numFromFile > max )
                {
                    max = numFromFile;
                }
                if (numFromFile < min)
                {
                    min = numFromFile;
                }
                break;

            // "View average temperature"
            case 3:
                sum += numFromFile;
                average = sum/24;
                break;
        }
    }


}
catch (ifstream::failure e) 
{
    //std::cerr << "Exception opening/reading file.";
    cout << e.what(); // Skriver ut vad felet egentligen är..
}

file.close(); 

// Skriver ut information till användaren baserat på valet som användaren har gjort
if (choice == 2)
{
    cout << "\nMaximum temperature: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << max <<" degrees Celcius\n";
    cout << "\nMinimum temperature: " << min << " degrees Celcius\n";
}

else if (choice == 3)
{
    cout << "\nAverage temperature: ";
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << average << " degrees Celcius\n";
}

continueOnKeyPressed();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much mr Bo Persson! Hehe, gissar att du är svensk. :-) You were correct!!

Comment: @BoPersson I think you should make this an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on an earlier comment:

Many compilers will but the debug and release versions of the executable in different directories. If `file.open("templog.txt");` works in release mode but not in debug mode, that's likely because the input file is located in the same directory as that version of the executable.

To make sure that you always find the file, use a full path name when calling the `open()` function.